# How to work with huge data in R Shiny and plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I need to work with very large files (over a million rows) in R Shiny, if possible.  It's not the data analytics that's the issue - it's figuring out how to display that much data in a reasonable amount of time - and more importantly, being able to interact with it through a range slider and data selection tools (lasso, point selections).  Before I go too much further with my project, I just have a general question about the feasibility of this and would like people's thoughts.  Basically, am I wasting my time on this?

I don't really need to display all the data at once (through time series plots), but it would be nice if that's possible.  If I could get the range slider to work faster, that would be huge.  I have not run across code that shows performance optimization for this type of thing, but it may be out there.

Anyway, if someone has thoughts on how to do this, or can point me in a direction to follow, that would be wonderful.  Thank you!

Comment: [Here](https://plotly.com/python/v3/compare-webgl-svg/#svg) you can find a UserWarning summarizing the issue: `Due to browser limitations, the Plotly SVG drawing functions have a hard time graphing more than 500k data points for line charts, or 40k points for other types of charts.` (from plotly.py which under the hood - just as the R API - uses plotly.js)

Comment: Does `echart4r` have this limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly loads all the data for the plot in the browser, so number of points usable in the graphics mainly depends on the client-side computer's performance and its bandwidth with the server. On my config, 1M point is a little slow to load (10s) but works OK afterwards.

You can check on your config with this little app:
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Plotly test"),
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "nb",
        "Number of points",
        choices = c(
          "1K"   = 1000,
          "10K"  = 10000,
          "100K" = 100000,
          "1M"   = 1000000,
          "10M"  = 10000000
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot")))
  )),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlotly(plot_ly(
      data.frame(x = 1:input$nb,
                 y = rnorm(input$nb)),
      x =  ~ x,
      y =  ~ y
    ) %>%
      add_lines())
  }
)
```

Comment: That works pretty quickly, actually.  Maybe my issue is that I'm using ggplotly to convert a ggplot graph to a plotly graph.  If that's the issue, that kind of stinks, actually, because there's so many ggplot graph features I really like.

Comment: I don't fully agree with the answer provided above. Unless I'm missing something, I'm trying to display a scatter plot with about 90k data points and it takes about 10mins to visualize. Internet connection is not the issue, so it seems plotly has some limitations with big data.

Comment: What happens when you try to plot 100k points using my sample app ?