# Shiny plotly slow plotting data

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to build a shiny dashboard using plotly to visualise some data but I encounter an issue where the plot becomes unusably slow with large numbers of data points. I found a similar question online ([How to work with huge data in R Shiny and plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392725/how-to-work-with-huge-data-in-r-shiny-and-plotly)) with a simple example, which I have been using to compare with my own data.
The code I am using is:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Plotly test"),
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "nb",
        "Number of points",
        choices = c(
          "1K"   = 1000,
          "10K"  = 10000,
          "100K" = 100000,
          "1M"   = 1000000,
          "10M"  = 10000000
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot")))
  )),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlotly(plot_ly(
      data.frame(x = 1:input$nb,
                 y = rnorm(input$nb)),
      x =  ~ x,
      y =  ~ y,
      type = "scattergl",
      mode= "markers"
    ))
  }
)
```

But after playing around with the example, I found the following issue:

If I create the data frame with the following values

```
data.frame(x = 1:input$nb,
                 y = rnorm(input$nb))
```

or

```
data.frame(x = rnorm(input$nb),
                 y = rnorm(input$nb))
```

The plot is generated quickly and I can interact with it.

If I instead create the dataframe with these values:

```
data.frame(x = 1:input$nb,
                 y = 1:input$nb)
```

it becomes unbearably slow and not practically useful.

My question is why does that particular combination result in such poor performance when both 1:input$nb and rnorm(input$nb) are the same dimensions?

Comment: [Here](https://plotly.com/python/v3/compare-webgl-svg/#svg) you can find a UserWarning summarizing the issue: `Due to browser limitations, the Plotly SVG drawing functions have a hard time graphing more than 500k data points for line charts, or 40k points for other types of charts.` (from plotly.py which under the hood - just as the R API - uses plotly.js)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ismirsehregal. Why is it though that in the example I've given that x = y = 1:input$nb is so much slower than x = y = rnorm(input$nb)? They are both plotting the same number of data points, yet the 1:input$nb case is significantly slower.

Comment: I can't reproduce your claim. I just did a benchmark - creating the plotly object with x and y = `rnorm(input$nb)` is slower than using `1:input$nb`.